# Regex to extract 2 groups of words delimited by multiple spaces

Tags: regex

Sorry, but stuck with this one...

I have a line that contains a key on the left and value on the right, with a number of spaces inbetween.

For example (I've had to use '_' to represent ' ' as Stackoverflow trims multiple spaces):

> PRODUCT NAME________________________________Super 4HP Mower
>
> PRODUCT MANUFACTURER_______________________________Honda

A key or value can match any set of letters, numbers, and characters such as ",',: etc.

How can I create a regex to extract the key and value separately?

Comment: Actually, this is *algorithmically impossible* unless you stipulate the "____" must have a minimum of 2 spaces and the key/value can only contain single spaces between words. Is this a valid assumption?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the data file is very poorly formatted. It's nigh on impossible to reliably process it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s{2,}` matches two or more spaces.

```
^(.*?)\s{2,}(.*)$
```

So the first `(.*?)` captures any number of characters until a double space is reached. `\s{2,}` matches two or more in-between spaces greedily. Then the next capturing group `(.*)` captures the value part. Just grab the key part from group index 1 and value part from group index 2.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tT9hF5/1)

In php, you could do like

```
$txt = <<<EOT
PRODUCT NAME Super            4HP Mower
PRODUCT MANUFACTURER           Honda
EOT;
preg_match_all('~^(.*?)\s{2,}(.*)$~m', $txt, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
print_r($match[2]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => PRODUCT NAME Super
    [1] => PRODUCT MANUFACTURER
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4HP Mower
    [1] => Honda
)
```